# How much memory is used by Java program

Tags: java, runtime, heap-memory

I've had a look around, and I've seen plenty of answers regarding the question of how much memory is being used by the JVM. These involve things such as calls to Runtime.totalMemory()/Runtime.freeMemory().

However, these don't take into account garbage collection. For example, say we have a large number of objects set to null, which have not yet been garbage collected. Calling Runtime.totalMemory() will show the total memory available as being far below what is actually technically available, as these null objects are still in memory.

So my question is this: is there any better way, be it in Java itself or data from a third party tool that can be ported into the program, to tell dynamically how much memory is being used by a Java program?

EDIT: This needs to be something that can be done in the code itself. Short of calling geObjectSize() on every message sent I can't think of another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can you a profiler like JProfiler and find out for a particular program the amount of memory used in real time.

Comment: Should've been specific (appropriate edit has been made) - this needs to be in the code itself. Either another method call, or a plugin (for example) that can be called from the code. Also does JProfiler ignore null objects? I feel like it just looks at memory usage with no regard for garbage collection, just the same as Runtime.totalMemory()

Answer (score 0):

Typically this information is not known prior to garbage collection.

After garbage collection, you can compute the amount of currently used memory with `Runtime.totalMemory()` and `Runtime.freeMemory()`, as you note.

> ... say we have a large number of objects set to null ...

Objects cannot be set to null. You may set *references* to objects to null. Setting a particular reference to an object to null **does not immediately mark the object as eligible for collection**.

Objects can be collected when they're no longer [reachable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability). Part of garbage collection is determining whether an object is no longer reachable.

One thing you could try is to suggest to the virtual machine that it free more memory. However, this is just a suggestion, so there might actually be more memory available after subsequent garbage collection.

```
public long getUpperBoundOfActiveMemoryUsage() {
    System.gc(); // Suggest that some garbage collection occur.

    return getUsedMemory();
}

public long getUsedMemory() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
    long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();
    long usedMemory = totalMemory - freeMemory;
    return usedMemory;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware it's the reference being set to null, but the call is "someObject = null" so I thought that was implied by what I said. But thank you, I figured there wasn't much I could do within Java itself.